# Updating nested properties from an object with bracket notation in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

So say I've got this interface and object with nested properties:

```js
interface Iobj {
  a: { a2:string };
  b: string;
}

const obj: Iobj = {
  a:{
    a2: "hello"
  }
  b: "world"
};
```

And I've got a strings that identify properties in obj:

```js
const prop = "a.a2"
// or
const prop = "b"
```

I'm trying to update `obj` with bracket notation but these statements give me the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

```
obj[prop] = "newString";
obj[prop as keyof Iobj] = "newString";
```

Seems like `obj[prop]` isn't being recognized as valid. Something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `obj["a.a2"]` won't work even in vanilla JS; you would have to use something like `lodash.get`.

Comment: Valid prop (e.g. `"b"`) works fine https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHsBGArZBvAKGWTgC58SAmUgZzClAHNkBfAbiOU3LoZEY4sCBBOhB1kWbOQw5kAXnycyhYsTjVkAIgAWEADb70WziwA0nbtoDu6KPoAmJ9sID0r5KPFhkAByjovgracAB0GlrI7shgOsA0yLYgAOQ+tlAA1pIwnugArlA0EMJeEv6BwVqYJgRSANrlvgC6lSAQ1gDK9ExabEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `obj['a.a2']` the Javascript expects `obj` to have been defined like this:

```
obj = {
  "a.a2": "hello"
}
```

However in you case `a2` is child of `a` so first you need to access `a` then access `a2`, That's why in your case `obj['a']['a2']` works instead. However if you still insist to use `a.a2` then you can use Lodash library which understands that key.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set