# Typescript: set value type of a deep nested object path

Tags: typescript

I would like to find a way to have all the `value types` for all the keys of a nested object paths.

I am successful to a certain extent but failed to set value type for a deep nested property inside an array object.

```
interface BoatDetails {
  boats: {
    boat1: string;
    boat2: number;
  };
  ships: Array<Ship>
}
interface Ship {
    shipName: string
}
const boatDetails: BoatDetails = {
  boats: {
    boat1: "lady blue",
    boat2: 1,
  },
  ships: [
      {shipName: "lacrose"}
  ]
};
```

For the above code I am able to successfully set the value type for the nested object paths like `boats.boat1` whose `value type is string`, `boats.boat2` whose `value type is number`, `ships` whose `value type is Array<Ship>`.

But unable to set `value type` for the the nested path `ships.0.shipName`.

I have taken reference for setting the deep nested object path types from the below link:
[Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object)

Below is my attempt towards setting the value type for deep nested object paths in typescript playground:

[Playground link for seeting value type for deep nested object paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAUg9gSwHYB4DSAaKAFAfFAXijSggA9gIkATAZyluACdkBzKAHyiQFcBbAEYQmUAPwBYAFBQZOUhSp0GzNp278hIidNkADACQBvNAF8jAInPzKNetjFRLUAFyOAdObOHsJ3VNku3BAAbsKBSCHCANxSsZKgkDhMIYRQANoRoUxYAAxYAIxYAExYAMxYACxYAKxYAGxYAOxYABxYAJwFef6y+YVQ+SUD5QNVA7UDDQPNA20DnVBFeVBuqzlpALobcQnQ2ACGwAAWtCgAKlgAItaK9LyCYUT5OfhEaZcbN7bpmcKfokEsoEzl8lHABAArCAAY2AYh6MkM6RIyCgAGsICA4AAzKBnDYAWlErhI5BsSkYLCQ7C49008J0ARkBmMvjU8GQ6CwB2OpzOaTQG25yWC7w2uFwCKZrl+TClJjSGKxuPxgUsO3A0AAMhB9qE+VdQXcNI8Bi9UmKjT9Ikx-oCwq4QWTblBwVDYQyAkiBVBUUqcXjCcTYIhUJgoDq9RA+QKhUkQmKJVAFf6VZ9XJYYpINYkAHLRyjUADykJhwDOmtShil+1clLYWYCAjrKmpjdkEUYrmrjKZ0JbVNY7ZkJmHruOwnzXagPaZsn7ykHY9HUhX2filanhZL7uAPJOqX3py3EGLpdhFcguCzAHob1BdlAT2fd0fUuZ9lYuOYBF-HJ3gD-cw4AnJgtyAgC3GhICQKOScCyg8wpEfZ8dzLSN9VSDDoxQVDz3LTVJUkO8H03AtTzQ2FsPoIgPyA381HMSDoMY2D4MYRC4mQSgmGxfZoWgM5kmgWdZAAGwgbFgEdYSMClFhWCOaS8VkqVqEOWtFzYVc4hIx8hIgCBqKw3V9XOYTrygEjaDgJgmBALBoTgPgwAQCSREAXg3AG6dwBsYg8wBqPakPTKwMozTOjd91OAT9GIkqS3CimLvwUpSEo0oC4uANxMrS6KvyC+9zBylKssSoCSuyyTSvSxiKoqsrYqqyr4pyhquAKxwcuKhBFOqvLGviirWpqrhVjcM1BigPhbOgMa1A68w6p61Klt6txVpW5aso2vrPxzQThOMohqPMwyymvDr9MO8KaJkcw2s6pqHsWrbcqSx6WqekaoAW7q1ueoavv65LXvq9LdJvAkoehmHYZh-coGCfYxJ4aBHwJZR9iYYA4dxvH8YJwmiYJ-acEOI4ADVkdR85uStI9aagCokyIexnW+FlkGxMI0ExEw3CMLmwgAJQLXwegBXmQCtVM8SlAFRcYenyZjKW42ZqUZABfcqZRiBzgFTE40V4AiLnGUbSlC2sh6Vw2YUb5ZbOCW8TSbBth0a3ogK4m4YRpG9dIxIMcUKBffDiPI8JuJsR4JBYQQOAkAYCBgF1mmeidB2lG9JUBzYDZXH2JBpZMOSdHt8k7BVxnmfLmQKeV450-1i4cCI3AAAo3UdLAwHJu2sAD1HXApgBKGcegQXFO92AN++OQgCFo+tqXMCfRJkJykCVsAtQQJWiAXo43FoMAxIQYBO-MDwx7HbelbE-ZGCl1I94PrKwDgMBO7vqUH7hF-bipp34cWSNQHgAlO6aygJ3fi0J+A8CfsAWy3Z0hkHztSQuUBi6l0cjwOyVA07UwgJgmk6gHhMAngQfAm8mTT1gfAxByDbJpAQYQpAxC9afGXkQOO1BJLIFPGPGBAQmF8CQYcVh7DkicJbjwmca45wyGSMAAhydxGSJQUwNhBDZFcNRhsMcI565MjdFKP+vYGGz01AGJ+L9MRQAAITL0cPwwRERqDr0nr2GQQDOHCDSPY4AatUjDwgMYqAqj1GukhMuHoJgejRKYMnN0WZEnrmAbxfi0AABCcBDiXFTvsNy9BRICAKcAWg3YpQVMOPkMhY46nACKDKE0TB2xKIYEcBAYBqlQAAIJ2X2CAFAABlHpYAiIZKyXxASUAJm9J8QEWgkzcz7D4KQrS1IdKSAAVAZpRToqlNcPkwpxTSlVh6M0-pdDmkNM6vsag0sBB63MKYmQzTWkDFMWXHoqzen9LSDAwwAKwDrM2RmJ+0ImBwFoBATwPQPZrn2TwMAUVTyLL6a4LFmwLR0LBRCrZ5hoqcKYPwJCkgTAezvFHAkYzIECVoLQWOYkxLS32K8tGcAU5wgnIjEhQdoDYlsg+OCByIBiTgAAdygMfegugbluHuboLAugwW0F0HS7VuMpDwoMRAaBOhDkXLErQeuirKm0GVZU-IqqegkpYMXVgElKWWP1S3I1nzKlHJKWai1Gr7U6DRRi6gWLaBSEsY+M5e4VaHhrjG31pSiLBUSDGt8tEblAQ1fRK1Nr6m5sONar5f51WTOtUYOkwg2RcDLYCgWhgq1MH5oSjZEA-AbjTZUo8Ld43NxISgRNprzXppVim+8QqoCjt5L2ogq9yFNrUD2EiTZbWNI6quw43ym23nvCYNQuKPY+0JrkgAolqIsAB1KAABJMZeIAASp7b1jLGQAVWfTqr936f2-qhkFAAVAB-wAGoBvqQJyiSD4eXSpYJQMV0BdDHwFYHXYuhoM4OhAJMAfLxUAVPL6Gg5A5VxovhiKAda+luByKfNZbbdDjRA7eiVEkEChAQ5htRyNfTMtRjxhDyRCNQCODKsm-a9aM0ri6Bmbdmb4EfAfX0LkJKbICdQKA0qenQiOPxpAIEomp3Uaofl4TJ0ipEMjMSHGv7MoQFyoIjACNujLCR3kbgmMAZvHED1JCvUHJ9cOgN5bqO0d6USoNd1gCX2LggFikasxAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606750/updating-nested-properties-from-an-object-with-bracket-notation-in-typescript

Comment: Sorry, it did not answer, but thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Well, I believe the problem is the `0` index is not enforced to present in `Array<Ship>` type. If you switch `ships`'s type to `[Ship]` your code works.

Comment: Note that the `V` type parameter in your `setValue()` function doesn't really do anything; you should probably remove it and replace all references to `V` with `PathValue<T, P>` directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be warned: the sort of [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) with [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) manipulation being done in `Paths<T>` and `PathValue<T, P>` are taxing on the compiler (you can easily get explicit recursion limit warnings, or worse, exponentially long compile times) and have various edge cases.

---

One edge case is that the `number`-to-`string` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) conversion done so easily with template literals has no easy inverse to turn `string` literals to equivalent `number` literals (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471042/string-type-to-number) and answer for more information).

So you are given an index type like `"0"` that you want to use as the key of an array type, but unless that array type happens to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), the compiler will not let you do it:

```
type Oops = (string[])["0"] // error!
// ------------------> ~~~
// Property '0' does not exist on type 'string[]'

type Okay = (string[])[0] // okay
// type Okay = string
```

And because `"0"` is not seen as a key of an array, `"ships.0.shipName"` fails when your `PathValue` type function evaluates `"0" extends keyof Ship[]`, and you are sad.  And without an official way to turn `"0"` into `0` or to have the compiler see `"0"` as `keyof Ship[]`, there's no canonical solution.

---

So you're kind of stuck with various workarounds.  One could be to ignore the possibility of tuples (which mostly already have explicit numeric-string indices except for those pesky [rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types)) and just make a workaround to `T[K]` that checks if `T` has a `number` index signature and that `K` is assignable to `` `${number}` ``, and if so, returns `T[number]`:

```
type Idx<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] :
    number extends keyof T ? K extends `${number}` ? T[number] : never : never;
```

which now works:

```
type TryThis = Idx<string[], "0">
// type TryThis = string

type StillWorks = Idx<string[], 0>
// type StillWorks = string
```

---

If we use that in your `PathValue<T, P>` type, like this:

```
type PathValue<T, P extends Paths<T, 4>> = P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
  ? Rest extends Paths<Idx<T, Key>, 4>
  ? PathValue<Idx<T, Key>, Rest>
  : never
  : Idx<T, P>
```

Then things start working:

```
setValue(
  boatDetails,
  `ships.0.shipName`,
  "titanic"
); // okay
/* function setValue<BoatDetails, "ships.0.shipName">(
     obj: BoatDetails, path: "ships.0.shipName", value: string
): BoatDetails */
```

---

There are other possible workarounds which might be able to tease more accurate results out of more arbitrary pairs of `T` and `K`, but I think this is good enough for now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8g9mAzlAvFAFI4AnAlgOwHMBtAXQEpiAiABitKgHpGoJts5sBCAWAChmUALQjRY8aIB8UAH5z+ggAodI2UFADkNDVAAmcCMnxxgrAB64sUOPiihImrHiJkN-fvegwA1gEMQqBhOBCQUxDQMgnB+IAosnrAxgcFE7nwJAJK6ZgA8ACoANFAA0tJoxebAEPi6yN4QIHAAZlB5UAD8rcTFDABc-FBQ+ACuALYARmyV1bVQ9Y0tbZ0VEGZVNcgABgAkAN4jE2wAvpsdXQeT2H1DEABuU70399hpCXnYIHkAFpaBWbkpUJFWhUSRxOzgaDvT4-ZBoQGvSFQADKwFwABt0QB1TjeOFQf45QFkIo0MECeJI1EY7G4-EIvhxZjMlmMNIeJEAKTgBByxSKijKJWmGyggKgAB8hmNLh0BlBFCLZuKpRcpu15TtdsUjnsqFQlchFZ19VBHlQAHRUXW7RQneWPfB3B5PNgAbnZ6SRyjugWITuepKKAEYigAmIoAZiKABYigBWIoANiKAHYigAOIoAThDNAK8uDoagwYjJejJbjJcTJZTJfTJazJdzUDD+agFs7NDIpERDkUvmAX0Q+SKABFDdLDthAsGyX6xwxVutZv7nVczgGXW1lzNkHBxgArCAAY1MGr4g12UG6UAIcwazVapCE7UeKzWe7FOBCkqnsovQZBi1HVTilbleX5BVB2HfJulIAVsDuYhF0kckgLNV0XkvKAjmIeYnzya59TSZgJHIiQByHKBbl8dFhmgBIhG-Xw1Ao9iOM4rjuI4vtoCor4ADU6IY0cFUnASR0KKAYzQwJFV3UUtQIJopmKBojgtPYVKmAAlQxgHtHDOn0qxFNmSSckJaT1JASRY3Qs4BOE+iICs7IxNs+yoFM4BHMddcHQJDzpMFUjGB48QBJokTGKRZiZmESLkpS1KJDSJphnwM9cBsMUIGAFzRPlHdP1Fa98IaR5AVIR5fHwAIjgLHCFLKiyYKkhz+EkdAD0PR5pLAGDHkUIpaNckaYKKtzQskcgoF2eVcBadBPCfIbqJQLaoCoQEqHmxacMGE8bCsMAABlLFMNANq+C1EDAdFcGAdBLX2j0jqgE78CsdFfCwWzAguq6LTABB0HID6MO+s6eXwKoZxuy6sAtJDdGGE8IHQeUMPQXwTxPMZhj+4BOEeCqzGqn8iFqqB6saopCfYapCtiqnnEIP81WweaUGkQ6MIw5aMHxwnRmJwdOGIJmkPh6aGC2tAst0CAmgICBdHIHHBcGUWiZJqWZZZ+XAl2I4oZ1qAkOAYZsFsPXxYN7Bpdt2XWdc0gLYwprtcGPrtch7XhdWyEnz+gGGigLhtqoZXVfV3R9oW32oDBggEeIcPgFshWYtcr2gOt23bD6gujnlcucKLu3rCPD7K-4dO2CafHoAAITgQcxwK3wMWQAWoHGTvgEQcntaHwdg3ZkIC4n4Aw0dGV3Qri3EB+JBHgAQXYfwcmRdfyUrpvsBbzGUXX5OcLX3AwAAOV8UYIGn1I+ErmHTDn7vgF79FR6gDuu49z7qbeUc8-4D0GHPKeO0-q6ACOMVyVBmoYTngvEsyDcIYOvhvG82trzYPvo-c0f0TwcEQBAA0ldBi9lfh9d+UBhhgF0IODW+8b5-zYWAMgfoB4EIfk-Ha394bYDGFQfgRwaFkVSsiDGmNECIEypiAIvgEGMTgPlUwQ5oDjQYhCBwTROB2C+NASY6I4AAHdU4dSgJsMBFooGbCKJsbBiBNhpXceRfg5D3YMWxjhT+QDf4YNscPRA9jh7BkcfKKgP56qEHRBQ-ggc+DeOmn4yBw8v4-0QMElxUScKMOYVUXQnDEBJI+gkABwBJLyQ6jkKpWS+7kkEJU4eNS0BUDAQaKUu116IG6TtOxUCBmdNCeEwcYYBnOL6VpfYS9sAnD-NM9hszuaaT4Y-TYHIHBVMktNWpQ5pr1MyYEnJ-82kdWaSwPR7cLlDkQPs+E1NOaqnmX+Q6ggUEROfoQD6nygKoMXtOP5LAjh-k4WQcKXE24AFFzowCxASZErQAASMKkXIgAKroo8bivF+KCUiDSKk2K6TB4nO-n3XJMyaD3XXoQiA+TBgxOevVXAJ4xF8EhkwFg0R-AKAAFRQEytlNEeUSWuWOYAylQSdouItLSjZFCeq+z6o8Bppyii3XNPKxV9L+FILzgxH5ST1UUuyVAAVbJGQ2qAA)

Comment: Thank you for such an amazing answer. Your knowledge on how typescript compiler works is helping typescript community a lot.

Comment: I've tried to modify your answer so instead of just replacing the value you can provide a function that has the current value as the first parameter and return the new value but couldn't figure it out. Is it possible?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB5Qpw) maybe?  I can't spend a lot of time focusing on followup questions on old q/a pairs; if you continue to have an issue you might want to open your own post to get more eyes on it. Good luck!